# Convert html to google docs or docx using drive api v3

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I'm trying to convert a html file (or preformatted html String) to Google Docs using `drive api v3` and `android studio`, using these lines:

```
MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("report.html")
                .setMimeType("text/html")
                .build();
```

(I extract the code from android-demos-master examples ) 
If I try put another mimetype like `"application/vnd.google-apps.document"`, my app crash. I want to upload the file and convert to Gdocs editor or Docx. I need convert before or after upload the file. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Using the python libraries, I found I had to specify two mimetypes:

1. Use `'application/vnd.google-apps.document'` when creating the metadata for the Drive file.  This is the type of file you want created - a Google Document.
2. Use `'text/html'` for the object representing uploaded data, as that is the type of the content.  In python, this were objects of type `io.MediaUpload` (file upload) or `io.MediaIoBaseUpload` (in-memory content).

I imagine it's something similar in Java.